# SQL- how to find different cases in the table

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks something like that:

country + form_ID + Original_form_Id + catalog

```
country  original_form   catalog form_id
1        6                  42           6
1        7                  368           7
1        69                  722         69
1        69                 1837         697
1        659                  2           659
1        666                 2           666
```

The point of original_form_id and form id: it is always equal, besides the case of 
country +original_form-id that go to different catalogs, meaning in this rows:

```
country  original_form   catalog form_id
1        69                  722         69
1        69                 1837         697
```

I need to create  from it 3 tables. One table is for all rows 1:1 (country+original_form to catalog), Second N:1 and Third 1:N cases. Meaning:

**First table 1:1**

```
country  original_form   catalog
1        6      42
1        7      368
```

**Second table 1:N**

```
country  original_form catalog
1        69      722
1        69     1837
```

**Third table N:1**

```
country  original_form   catalog
1        659      2
1        666     2
```

I implement it using the answer bellow but there are duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO Mapping_1ToN
(SELECT  ot1.Country_id, ot1.original_form_id, ot1.catalog_id, ot1.Local_id
FROM    mappingtable ot1
WHERE   EXISTS -- Multiple catalogs for same country+form
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mappingtable ot2
        WHERE   ot1.country_id = ot2.country_id
                AND ot1.original_form_id = ot2.original_form_id
                AND ot1.form_id <> ot2.form_id
                AND ot1.catalog_id <> ot2.catalog_id
        ));

INSERT  INTO Mapping_NTo1
(SELECT  ot1.Country_id, ot1.original_form_id, ot1.catalog_id, ot1.Local_id
FROM    mappingtable ot1
WHERE   EXISTS -- Multiple forms for same catalog
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mappingtable ot2
        WHERE   ot1.country_id = ot2.country_id
                AND ot1.original_form_id <> ot2.original_form_id
                AND ot1.catalog_id = ot2.catalog_id
        ));


INSERT  INTO Mapping_1To1
(SELECT  ot1.Country_id, ot1.original_form_id, ot1.catalog_id, ot1.Local_id
FROM    mappingtable ot1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS -- form+catalog unique per country
        (
        SELECT  ot2.Country_id, ot2.original_form_id, ot2.catalog_id, ot2.Local_id
        FROM    mappingtable ot2
        WHERE   ot1.country_id = ot2.country_id
                AND (
                    (ot1.original_form_id = ot2.original_form_id AND ot1.catalog_id <> ot2.catalog_id AND ot1.form_id = ot2.form_id)
                    OR
                    (ot1.original_form_id <> ot2.original_form_id AND ot1.catalog_id = ot2.catalog_id)
                )
        ));
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote answers and mark them as accepted.

Comment: But i didnt get an answer that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First table:

```
insert  Table1
select  *
from    OriginalTable ot1
where   not exists -- form+catalog unique per country
        (
        select  *
        from    OriginalTable ot2
        where   ot1.country = ot2.country
                and (
                    (ot1.form = ot2.form and ot1.catalog <> ot2.catalog)
                    or
                    (ot1.form <> ot2.form and ot1.catalog = ot2.catalog)
                )
        )
```

Second table:

```
insert  Table2
select  ot1.*
from    OriginalTable ot1
where   exists -- Multiple catalogs for same country+form
        (
        select  *
        from    OriginalTable ot2
        where   ot1.country = ot2.country
                and ot1.form = ot2.form
                and ot1.catalog <> ot2.catalog
        )
```

Third table:

```
insert  Table3
select  ot1.*
from    OriginalTable ot1
where   exists -- Multiple forms for same country+catalog
        (
        select  *
        from    OriginalTable ot2
        where   ot1.country = ot2.country
                and ot1.form <> ot2.form
                and ot1.catalog = ot2.catalog
        )
```

To find rows that would end up in both Table2 and Table3, run:

```
select  *
from    OriginalTable ot1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    OriginalTable ot2
        where   ot1.country = ot2.country
                and ot1.form <> ot2.form
                and ot1.catalog = ot2.catalog
        )
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    OriginalTable ot2
        where   ot1.country = ot2.country
                and ot1.form = ot2.form
                and ot1.catalog <> ot2.catalog
        )
```

Comment: What about the 1:1 case? Why do you just choose everything?

Comment: Aha, I thought `1:1` meant a plain copy.  Updated so it only includes rows with one `(form, catalog)` combination per country.

Comment: @Andomar in your first table .. did you mean this `select  ot1.*
from    OriginalTable ot1`

Comment: In my original table I have 1585 pairs of country and form id (may be the same, may be not). Now when i count rows in three tables i get: 171 rows in N:1 case, 1:N - 123 rows and 1297 rows for 1:1 case - which in sum 1591 - and that is more than original table so somewhere it is wrong

Comment: I think he did, because otherwise there is no meaning to ot1

Comment: @sansix: Yeah, `ot1` added. @Alexandra: There might be a row with both multiple countries and multiple catalogs.  Those would end up in both table2 and table3.

Comment: i match form+country to catalog. So i can have one country+form matched to one catalog or one country+form matched to different catalogs or couple country+form matched to the same catalogs

Comment: I've added a query that should display rows that end up in both Table2 and Table3, can you run that?

Comment: zero answers have been found. I think the problem is in the 1:1 Query

Comment: I run this query: SELECT country_Id, form_Id, COUNT(catalog_id)
FROM Mapping_1To1
GROUP BY country_Id, form_Id
HAVING COUNT(catalog_id)>1     - for 1:1 table and i found one result where COUNT(catalog_id)=2

Comment: The query for Table2 and Table3 was wrong, updated it.  If there are duplicate rows, they'd end up in Table1, check `select country, form, catalog from OriginalTable group by country, form, catalog having count(*) > 1`

Comment: I dont see the change in table 2 and 3